# Filtering on many-to-many relations that fulfill a set of criteria

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-orm

With the following models:

```
class OrderOperation(models.Model):
    ordered_articles = models.ManyToManyField(Article,
                                              through='orders.OrderedArticle')

class OrderedArticle(models.Model):
    order_operation = models.ForeignKey(OrderOperation)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
```

`articles = ... # some queryset containing multiple articles`

If I want to find order operations containing at least one article, this works as expected:

```
OrderOperation.objects.filter(ordered_articles__in=articles)
```

However, if I want to find order operations with all the articles in the order, what is the correct way to do it?

`OrderOperation.objects.filter(ordered_articles=articles)` raises a `ProgrammingError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression` error (I understand why actually).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
order_operations = OrderOperation.objects.all()
for article in articles:
    order_operations = order_operations.filter(ordered_articles=article)
```

It's just one query, but with an inner join per article. For more than a few articles Willem’s more ingenious solution should perform better.

Comment: Thanks! I switch to this as accepted answer as it is simpler to read, ans perform ok when there are a few articles, as you said :)

Answer (score 1):

We can first construct a `set` of articles:

```
articles_set = set(articles)
```

Next we can count the number of articles related to the `OrderOperation` that appear in that set, and check if that number is equal to the size of that set, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count

OrderOperation.objects.filter(
    ordered_articles__in=articles_set
).annotate(
    narticles=Count('ordered_articles')
).filter(
    narticles=len(articles_set)
)
```

Since in a `ManyToManyField`, each `Article` can occur once per `OrderOperation`, if the number of related `Article`s that are in the `article_set` is the same as the number of elements in the `article_set`, we thus know that the two sets are the same.

This will create a query that looks like:

```
SELECT orderoperation.*
       COUNT(orderoperation_article.article_id) AS narticle
FROM orderoperation
JOIN orderoperation_article ON orderoperation_id = orderoperation.id
WHERE orderoperation.article_id IN (article_set)
GROUP BY orderoperation.id
HAVING COUNT(orderoperation_article.article_id) = len(article_set)
```

where the `article_set` and `len(article_set)` are of course replaced by the primary keys of the articles in the set, or the number of elements in that set.

Comment: Hi :) It seems that `filter(ordered_articles__in=articles_set)` has the exact same effect than `filter(ordered_articles__in=articles)`. In both cases, it filters order operations that contains at least 1 of the articles.

Comment: @DavidD.: yes that is correct, we filter on the *related* set, the point is not the filtering, we then should `.annotate(..)` the number of articles that satisfy that condition, and then filter on that number, so the `.annotate(..).filter(..)` part eventually does the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works well! Unfortunately, I'm unable to use your solution because I oversimplified my question as I'm using subquery. May I ask you to take a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54863449/django-how-to-annotate-m2m-or-onetomany-fields-using-a-subquery) ? Thanks a lot.