# How to filter objects using multiple-choice in many-to-many relations

Tags: django, django-views

In this simplified example, I have models named `Movie` and `Genre`, in many-to-many relationship.
The template shows multiple-choice box where I can select multiple genres, which are returned to the view as an array, for example `genres = ['Action', 'Comedy', 'Drama']`.

Now, I need to filter `Movie` object, which has exactly those three genres (the actual number of choices may vary).

I known that I can filter single choice with `Movie.objects.filter(genre__name__exact = 'Action')`. I known that I can use
`Movie.objects.filter(genre__name__in = ['Action', 'Comedy', 'Drama'])`, but that returns movies which have at least one of the genres from the array, I don't need that.

What I need is a queryset of movies that has exactly ['Action', 'Comedy', 'Drama'], no more, no less.

I also tried getting the genre queryset first:
`Genre.objects.filter(name__in = ['Action', 'Comedy', 'Drama'])`, and than using this queryset to filter `Movie` object, but I don't know if it's 
even possible.

I had read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/) on making queries, but didn't find the solution there.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54841016/django-filtering-many-to-many-field-with-whole-same-queryset/54844688#54844688) you can find two solutions, a simple one for small amounts for data and a more complicated one for larger tables.

Comment: Thank you, the simple solution worked very well for me. I've marked the question as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Q-objects. Those can also be used dynamically i.e. connected in any number [See here.](https://micropyramid.com/blog/querying-with-django-q-objects/)